# No entiendo porqué no funciona el siguiente código de Python

Tags: python

Tengo un problema al ejecutar la función `change_to_mop_thermo` que copio en este post. La función (interna) `out_to_mop_let` no debería ejecutarse si la variable let es igual a None y está haciéndolo.

El error está relacionado a las últimas líneas del siguiente script:

```
 def change_to_mop_thermo(infile, namedir="",charge=0, let=None, gnorm=None, separate=True, hamiltonian="PM6", calctype="opt", multiplicity="singlet", eps=None): #~this is a function
        #armado de la salida
        if calctype=="thermo(298,298,0)":
            calctype1="thermo"
        else: 
            calctype1=calctype    

        outfile=infile.split(".")[0] + "-" + calctype1 + "-" + hamiltonian + ".mop"
        if gnorm !=None:
            gnorm="gnorm="+str(gnorm)
        else: 
            gnorm= " "
        if let !=None:
            let=str(let)
        else:
            let=" "
        if eps !=None:
            eps="eps=" + str(eps)
        else:
            eps = " "
        keywords = "%s  %s  %s %s %s %s charge=%i"%(hamiltonian, let, calctype, multiplicity, eps, gnorm, charge)    

        #change directory of outfile  #~the problem is near this lines, i suppose
        if namedir!="":
            outfile= namedir + "/" + outfile
        if let!=None:
            return out_to_mop_let(infile, outfile, keywords) #~this function should be executed only if let is different from none, but it is being executed always
        else:
            return out_to_mop(infile, outfile, keywords)
```

Por completitud escribo como llamo a la función `change_to_mop_thermo` (en otro script):

```
change_to_mop_thermo(solvfile,"../thermo", charge=definir_carga(solvfile),calctype="thermo(298,298,0)",eps="80", gnorm="0.01")
```

Podrían ayudarme a resolverlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anteriormente tienes un condicional idéntico que asigna un nuevo valor a  `let`:

```
if let !=None:
    let=str(let)
else:
    let=" "
```

Si `let` es `None` pasa al `else` y ahora `let` es un string con un espacio : `" "`. Cuando llegas al siguiente condicional `let` **nunca** va a ser `None`, esta variable siempre es una cadena en este punto.

O bien cambias el segundo condicional a `if let == " "` o reordenas el código.

Comment: muuuuchas gracias